# Jupyter notebook uses my gpu, however pycharm with virtual environment does not. How do I get the exact environment set up as my notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, conv-neural-network

As the title says. I installed the CUDA toolkit, did the conda source forge isntall of tensorflow gpu. And it works perfectly in my jupyter notebook. I am running a CNN and it takes about 10 seconds every epoch. I do the same thing for my pycharm IDE and I get and error:

```
 File "C:\Users\StackoverflowUser\Anaconda3\envs\Working_Gpu_Environment\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1472, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
     [[metrics/acc/Mean/_127]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I am thinking it has to be something to do with the environment I am using especially because the last file the error is triggered from is from the pat where my virtual environment is stored. However, my lack of expertise is holding me back, I tried looking for the default environment my Notebook uses but could not figure out how. Are there any other ways?

Comment: sorry I mean my pycharm IDE

Comment: Did you set the Pycharm virtual env as the same environment as your Jupyter Notebook uses?

Comment: sorry maybe the question was not clear, but how do I check my jupyter notebook's environment? I realize they are different, just want to peek into jupyter. Right now jupyter just sets up something by default.